# how to replace radio buttons with newer radio buttons on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Below is the code which creates radio buttons on button click, but i want it to replace previous radio buttons with newly generated ones on each button click instead of just appending to the old ones. Can someone please help.

```
<div id="radio_home">
            <input type="button" name="check" value="GENERATE RADIO BUTTON" onclick="gen();"><br/>
        </div>
        
        
        <script>
            var radio_home=document.getElementById("radio_home");
            
            function makeRadioButton(name, value, text){
            
                var label=document.createElement("label");
                var radio=document.createElement("input");
                radio.type="radio";
                radio.name=name;
                radio.value=value;
                label.appendChild(radio);
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            return label;
            }
            
            function gen(){
                var yes_button=makeRadioButton("yesbutton", "yes", "Oh Yea! DO it");
                radio_home.appendChild(yes_button);
                
                var no_button=makeRadioButton("nobutton", "no", "Oh No! DON'T do it");
                radio_home.appendChild(no_button);
                
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the innerHTML of your element like this

```
radio_home.innerHTML = ""; //to empty the inner HTML of radio_home

radio_home.appendChild(yes_button); //then append child to it
```

You also need to take your button out of radio_home div as it will be removed once you empty the innerHTML